# ExtJS Chart Time and Category Axis

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, extjs4

Recently I've encountered time axis bug because of which I get incorrect axis labels: two duplicate dates and one missing date. As far as I understand it occurs when start and end dates have different time zones (can't do anything about that, it happened because of change from DST to summer time). The bug seems to be well known and apparently it hasn't been solved yet:

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?29351-OPEN-454-TimeAxis-Bug
www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?267174

As a quick workaround for this bug I am using category axis which presents all the labels correctly, but it has another problem. The category axis does not appear (empty space where the actual axis supposed to be) until the store is loaded. In my case, I actually want to show the axis even when the store hasn't been loaded and there is no data to display. To get the desired behavior I tried the following:

- Manually load some "place holder/filler" data into the store using add, loadData and loadRawData store methods. None of which seem to have any effect on category axis - it still doesn't appear.
- Show time axis until I can get data from the server and then replace it with category axis. This time I've encountered another bug. To replace chart axis you have to use chart.axis.remove(), chart.axis.add(), chart.surface.removeAll() and then chart.redraw(). The problem is that after surface.removeAll() and redraw(), axes and grid lines are drawn on top of my series and it looks somewhat like this:

http://s12.postimg.org/y3tvbrf5p/image.png

This might be a result of the following bug:
www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188158-BUG-4.0.x-4.1rc1-Chart-line-series-zIndex-not-set-correctly

**Any suggestions how to make category axis appear even when data is not loaded from the server?**

Comment: Which Version of Ext exactly are you using?

Comment: The time axis bug is present in all ext 4 versions. If you live in europe, following fiddle will show the bug in action:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/52r
If you are from US, you'll need to adjust start date to be before 09-Mar (switch from DST to summer time).